# How to transform the bases added to a bravais lattice?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

I tried to treat body-centered cubic as a simple cubic with a set of bases.
If the lattice spacing of a simple cubic is $a$, I choose the bases to be $(0,0,0)$ and $(a/2,a/2,a/2)$ distinctively.
There are relations,which can transform the primitive vectors into reciprocal lattice vectors.However, I have no idea how to transform the bases $(0,0,0)$ and $(a/2,a/2,a/2)$.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you try to do, you need 3 vectors to define the primitive unit cell. Traditionally, they are taken as

$$\begin{align}
a' &= \frac{a}{2}(\bar{1},1,1),\\
b' &= \frac{a}{2}(1,\bar{1},1),\\
c' &= \frac{a}{2}(1,1,\bar{1}).
\end{align}$$

You can then apply the usual formula to find the reciprocal cell vectors $(a'^*,b'^*,c'^*)$.

Comment: Definitely,you misunderstood.What I want to deal with are the bases.

Comment: Could you clarify what are those relations «which can transform the primitive vectors into reciprocal lattice vectors» then?